# How to format a Date in MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting a date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

I know other possible formats in JavaScript Date object but I did not get on how to format the date to `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format.

Please let me know if you come across such problem.

Comment: All the methods are there on the date object.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Corbin, I tried with some predefined formats but I did not get a predefined format for MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: date.toISOString().replace(/([^T]+)T([^\.]+).*/g, '$1 $2')

Comment: new Date(Date.now()).toISOString().replace('T', ' ')

Comment: new Date().toISOString().replace('T', ' ').substr(0, 19)

Comment: Closed because extremely concise, specific, to the point, and helpful, so violates SO policies. Readers are instead advised to follow alternate thread that is several paragraphs long and vague.

Comment: var d = new Date(),
  date_format_str = d.getFullYear().toString()+"-"+
     ("0"+(d.getMonth()+1)).substr(-2)+"-"+
   ("0"+d.getDate()).substr(-2)+" "+
      ("0"+d.getHours()).substr(-2)+":"+
      ("0"+d.getMinutes()).substr(-2)+":"+
      ("0"+d.getSeconds()).substr(-2);

Answer (score 172, accepted):

[**Addendum 12/2022**]: Here's a [library](https://github.com/KooiInc/dateformat) to format dates using [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

[**Addendum 01/2024**]: And here is a [(ES-)Date manipulation library](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler)

Try something like this

```
var d = new Date,
    dformat = [d.getMonth()+1,
               d.getDate(),
               d.getFullYear()].join('/')+' '+
              [d.getHours(),
               d.getMinutes(),
               d.getSeconds()].join(':');
```

If you want leading zero's for values < 10, use this number extension

```
Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
    var  len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
    return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
}
// usage
//=> 3..padLeft() => '03'
//=> 3..padLeft(100,'-') => '--3'
```

Applied to the previous code:

```
var d = new Date,
    dformat = [(d.getMonth()+1).padLeft(),
               d.getDate().padLeft(),
               d.getFullYear()].join('/') +' ' +
              [d.getHours().padLeft(),
               d.getMinutes().padLeft(),
               d.getSeconds().padLeft()].join(':');
//=> dformat => '05/17/2012 10:52:21'
```

See this code in [jsfiddle][1]

[**edit 2019**] Using ES20xx, you can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and the new `padStart` string extension.

```js
const dt = new Date();
const padL = (nr, len = 2, chr = `0`) => `${nr}`.padStart(2, chr);

console.log(`${
    padL(dt.getMonth()+1)}/${
    padL(dt.getDate())}/${
    dt.getFullYear()} ${
    padL(dt.getHours())}:${
    padL(dt.getMinutes())}:${
    padL(dt.getSeconds())}`
);
```

Comment: Thanks Kooilnc, I tried                                            var d = new Date();
var dformat = [d.getMonth().join('/') + d.getDate().join('/')+ d.getFullYear()].join('/')+' ' +d.getHours().join(':')+d.getMinutes().join(':')+d.getSeconds()]; but i am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] " . Do you know the reason? Thanks for the help

Comment: Your code is completely wrong (you can't use `d.getMonth().join('/')`). Try copying/running the code I gave in my answer *without changing it*. I have added a jsfiddle link for you

Comment: Your example is incorrect.  He's asking for MM/dd and you've supplied the format dd/MM (european style).

Comment: @JeffFischer Yep, that's why my answer stated "Try something *like* this". Anyway, adjusted the answer especially for you.

Comment: hi why did you used +1 after getMonth()? I tried removing it and it gave me incorrect month. Is some kind of conversion is happening?

Comment: okay got it. It gives months from 0 to 11.

Comment: above syntax helpful in my date formation

Answer (score 72):

You can always format a date by extracting the parts and combine them using string functions in desired order:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  let datePart = [
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    date.getDate(),
    date.getFullYear()
  ].map((n, i) => n.toString().padStart(i === 2 ? 4 : 2, "0")).join("/");
  let timePart = [
    date.getHours(),
    date.getMinutes(),
    date.getSeconds()
  ].map((n, i) => n.toString().padStart(2, "0")).join(":");
  return datePart + " " + timePart;
}

let date = new Date();
console.log("%o => %s", date, formatDate(date));
```

Comment: Should be using getDate() for the date. Can't edit because SO want more than 6 chars edited... sigh.

Answer (score 6):

```
var d = new Date();

var curr_date = d.getDate();

var curr_month = d.getMonth();

var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
```

using this you can format date.

you can change the appearance in the way you want then

for more info you can visit [here](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)

Answer (score -3):

```
var d = new Date();

// calling the function
formatDate(d,4);


function formatDate(dateObj,format)
{
    var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
    var curr_date = dateObj.getDate();
    var curr_month = dateObj.getMonth();
    curr_month = curr_month + 1;
    var curr_year = dateObj.getFullYear();
    var curr_min = dateObj.getMinutes();
    var curr_hr= dateObj.getHours();
    var curr_sc= dateObj.getSeconds();
    if(curr_month.toString().length == 1)
    curr_month = '0' + curr_month;      
    if(curr_date.toString().length == 1)
    curr_date = '0' + curr_date;
    if(curr_hr.toString().length == 1)
    curr_hr = '0' + curr_hr;
    if(curr_min.toString().length == 1)
    curr_min = '0' + curr_min;

    if(format ==1)//dd-mm-yyyy
    {
        return curr_date + "-"+curr_month+ "-"+curr_year;       
    }
    else if(format ==2)//yyyy-mm-dd
    {
        return curr_year + "-"+curr_month+ "-"+curr_date;       
    }
    else if(format ==3)//dd/mm/yyyy
    {
        return curr_date + "/"+curr_month+ "/"+curr_year;       
    }
    else if(format ==4)// MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
    {
        return curr_month+"/"+curr_date +"/"+curr_year+ " "+curr_hr+":"+curr_min+":"+curr_sc;       
    }
}
```

Comment: -1, really bad coding here