# Changing the time and date format for Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, the title briefly explains my question. I'm creating a kick feature for my bot and it's been working very well. The only problem (not major) I have is with the section where it sends an embed with the kick information to the **#incidents** channel which is only accessible to Bots and Staff. I've made a new Discord user account that I've created and joined it to the server. I tested my remove command and it works and does what I intend.

```
var incidentembed = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("User removed")
    .setDescription("**" + ruser + "** was successfully removed from the server.") /** ruser declares the user that was removed. **/
    .setColor("#3937a5")
    .addField("Time assigned", message.createdAt, true)
    .addField("Assigned by", `<@${message.author.id}>`, true)
    .addField("Reason", rreason, false); /** rreason declares the reason that the staff member inputted. **/
bot.channels.get("466904829550264322").send(incidentembed); /** The ID points out the #incidents channel. **/
```

[image: Embed look]

(yes, ClassyAss is my Discord username.)

As you can tell by the screenshot, there is something evidently wrong with the **Time assigned** field.  I am using **message.createdAt** to generate this date and time, however, how it is formatted is cluttered and confusing.

I want the time and date format to be set out as **DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM** based on Australian Eastern Standard Time (AEST). How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using the embed you can use Discord to display the time and date (it would also convert to the timestamp of the user).
[`embed.setTimestamp()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=setTimestamp).

```
var incidentembed = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("User removed")
    .setDescription("**" + ruser + "** was successfully removed from the server.") /** ruser declares the user that was removed. **/
    .setColor("#3937a5")
    .setTimestamp(message.createdAt)
    .addField("Assigned by", `<@${message.author.id}>`, true)
    .addField("Reason", rreason, false); /** rreason declares the reason that the staff member inputted. **/
bot.channels.get("466904829550264322").send(incidentembed); /** The ID points out the #incidents channel. **/
```

---

Or if you still want to format the date you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10632399/6195472).

```
var d = new Date,
dformat = [d.getMonth()+1,
       d.getDate(),
       d.getFullYear()].join('/')+' '+
      [d.getHours(),
       d.getMinutes(),
       d.getSeconds()].join(':');
```

Credit goes to [KooiInc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58186/kooiinc).