# SQL DATETIME to Nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js

I have my datetime SQL columns with all my data  in UTC, for example:

> 2020-05-31 16:59:35

But when I extract it from my app with this query:

```
select expdate 
from tempbans 
where banid = '${tempVars("banid")}'
```

I get this output:

```
Sun May 31 2020 18:59:35 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)
```

I know the local machine is on UTC+2 but I don't want it to auto-convert it for me, I want the output in my app to remain UTC.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the node part but .js part behaving like this. Maybe you should try converting your output before print it.

```
var datee = new Date('2020-05-31 16:59:35');
console.log(datee.getFullYear() + '-' +('0' + (datee.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+ '-' +  ('0' + datee.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' '+datee.getHours()+ ':'+('0' + (datee.getMinutes())).slice(-2)+ ':'+datee.getSeconds());
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1hc8Led//)

Extremely useful source : [How to format a Date in MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss format in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632346/how-to-format-a-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-format-in-javascript)