# Apexcharts updateOptions xaxis label

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I have such an example in which I would like to change the series of data on the xaxis along with changing the formatting:

```
ApexCharts.exec("chartID", "updateOptions", {
 xaxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    categories: dates_string_array,
    tickAmount:5,
        labels: {
      show: true,
        rotate: -45,
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}
  },
});
```

The `categories` substitution corrects (it is an array with dates as string) however, this formatting `format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'` still doesn't work - the format is exactly what the dates in the `dates_string_array` are in.
In this case, do I need to use `formatter` to overwrite these values?

An example of default format one of array elements:
`2022-01-01 10:00`

I would like to format it like this:
`2022-01-01`

Comment: If you talking about formatting categories  in tooltip then yes, you need to use `formatter `

Comment: @PatrykLaszuk Yes, that's exactly what it tried to do.
Category input is an array of dates in the format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`, but when trying to call something like this:
`formatter: function (val) {return val.toString()}`
such an error appears: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')`
this is some weird format, I have no idea what kind of format

Comment: Add `if(val)` before return

Comment: @PatrykLaszuk Yes you are right, just this condition was enough and formatting on xaxis works correctly.
What do I need to do if the tooltip I would still like in the previous format? 
The xaxis in `yyyy-MM-dd` format as currently and the tooltip `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`?
I tried with `tooltip` `x: {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"}`, but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Try `formatter` instead `format`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10632346/16537039) might help you with formatting